# Web Scraping with Python: Iinput text and click a button

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I was doing some web scraping with python (Linkedin site) and got stuck with the following 2 issues: 1) How do I input text on a search bar? 2) How to click a button? First, this is the search bar code:

```
<input aria-autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" 
placeholder="Búsqueda" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" id="a11y-
ember6214" role="combobox" class="ember-text-field ember-view" aria-
expanded="false">
```

To input the text I was using the xpath (and it works) but it changes every time I login into the site:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a11y-ember997"]')
search.send_keys('MedMake')
```

So could I use instead part of the input bar code above so that I can rerun my script multiple times?

My second point is 2) how to click a button. Again I was using the xpath but it changes after every login. My code was:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-search-controls-wormhole"]/button')
button.click()
```

I inspected the button code and I would instead like to use data-vertical="PEOPLE" or any other of this unique fields (the tag button is not enough since there are many buttons on Linkedin site). By the way,how are all these inner fields called? I believe part of my problem arises from the lack of html code understanding.

```
<button data-vertical="PEOPLE" data-control-
name="vertical_nav_people_toggle" data-ember-action="" data-ember-
action-8620="8620" data-is-animating-click="true">
Gente
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` attribute values are dynamic you can use other attributes with static values:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Búsqueda"]')
search.send_keys('MedMake')
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Gente"]')
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

First one use xpath

```
//input[contains(@class,'ember-text-field')]
```

Second one use the xpath

```
//button[@class='vertical_nav_people_toggle']
```